# Updating specific positions in 2D numpy array with a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have a `base` numpy  array

```
base=np.zeros((5,5))
```

I have to now update a few values in the array given by indices in another array, say

```
update_indices=np.array([0,1,4,3,0,2,3,2]. dtype='int32')
```

and their corresponding update values

```
update_values=np.array([3,5,4,6,7,2,1,4])
```

The update method goes as follows

```
for index1,value1 in zip(update_indices,update_values):
    for index2,value2 in zip(update_indices, update_values):
        base[index1,index2]+=value1*value2
```

This works ok for small cases, but in case the size of `base` and `update_indices` gets large, the method becomes unfeasible due to being slow. Is there a better way to do this?

A high memory requirement solution such as the following was tried. I tried to create a 3D matrix of indices using

```
indices2=np.empty((len(update_indices),len(update_indices),2))
```

and then stored indices as

```
indices2[:,:,0]=update_indices[:,None]
indices2[:,:,1]=update_indices[:,None]
```

and then update the `base` as

```
base[indices[:,:,0],indices[:,:,1]]=update_values[:,None]*update_values[None,:]
```

This however will increase the memory requirements by too much.
Are there methods that can meet in the middle by not taking too much memory and being faster?

I am trying to use `np.add.at`, but unable to understand how to cast it in this case.

Comment: You can transform the base matrix to an array with `np.flatten(base)`. Then you can simplify the nested loops to a single loop which will decrease the running time.

Comment: Wouldn't that still be running at the same time requirements since the overall number of updation via loop still remain the same?

Answer (score 0):

If the memory requirements for the full matrix of indices are too large, I'd suggest trying row-by-row updating:

```
for i, v in zip(update_indices, update_values):
     np.add.at(base, (i, update_indices), v * update_values)
```

Comment: This one will fail if elements in ```update_indices``` are repeated.